# Importing own file into Java class

Tags: java, import

Okay, not sure if this would work.. but would it be possible, to use my own Java file that has certain required methods in it, to be imported into my Java class just like any other import? Or does it have a special way?

Answer (score 2):

If your Java file contains a proper Java class enclosing the methods mentioned above, and it is visible to the compiler (i.e. either its source file is on the compiler source path or its class file is on the compiler classpath), you can just import it like any other classes.

Have you tried it? Do you have any specific problem?

Comment: So I can just do.. `import API;`?

Comment: @NathanKreider, if your class is named `API` and it is in the default package, then yes. Note that it is not recommended to put classes in the default package, but for starters it is OK.

Comment: @NathanKreider, you are using the Ubuntu command line for what? And what is the exact command you are trying to execute?

Comment: I have the class named Methods, and currently it just contains a simple void method that contains `add(new JLabel("Hello!"));`. If I change it to a static method, it gives me a non-static method blah blah error. using Methods.label(); without it being static gives me a "cannot be referenced from a static context" error.

Comment: @NathanKreider, this has not much to do with `import` then. What the compiler is trying to tell you (in both cases, but in different ways) is that you can't call nonstatic methods without an instance of the containing class. E.g. if you want to call your nonstatic `Methods.label()`, you need `Methods m = new Methods(); m.label();` .

Comment: I added the Methods m = new Methods(); to my public class wrapper, and it still doesn't work. I get no errors, but I also get no output.

Comment: @NathanKreider, in other words, your original problem is solved, and now you see the next one. I would suggest you post another question with this new problem. At any rate, please post the (relevant parts of the) code you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

If that method is static and visible in your scope, you can use import static. It will make the imported static method look like it is in your class. For example, if your code parse a lot of integers, you can use

```
import static Integer.parseInt;
```

And then the parseInt method will be visible and invokable directly:

```
int parsed = parseInt("123");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is only required if your other class is in a different namespace. if they are in the same namespace (this includes the default empty namespace), and you 'tell' the compiler about both files, you don't need to use import statements.

If however class `A` is in namespace `org.example.stuffA`, and you want to use it in class `B` in `org.example.stuffB`, you'll need to use a `import org.example.stuffA.A` statement, or hard-link it in the document (`new org.example.stuffA.A()` for example).

In the namespaces example, you still need to make sure the compiler is able to find the required classes. In both cases you also need to make sure the methods you need are of the correct permission type, they would probably need to be `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Static methods or by create Object of it & Use.

```
public class abc
{
    public static MyMethod()
    {
        // ..
    }
}
```

---

```
public class pqr
{
    abc.MyMethod();
}
```

Another Way

```
public class abc
{

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // ..
    }
}
```

---

```
public class pqr
{
    abc Obj=new abc();
    Obj.MyMethod();
}
```